# How to extract a json value inside an array inside a json in SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json

I have a JSON being returned in my query called MetaDataJSON, inside which is an array of JSONs called Results.  Inside each JSON in Results are two values, Chronic and Probability.  There are a couple other tables that have been joined too.  Is there a way to get Chronic in a column by itself?  Right now I have gotten this far (table and variable names have been made generic):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    JSON_QUERY(mdj.value, '$.Results[0]') [Results]
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.parameter1 = t1.parameter1
    AND t2.parameter2 = 'ASDF'
JOIN table3 t3 ON oad.parameter3 = oa.parameter3 
    AND t3.parameter4 = 11
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t3.MetaDataJSON) as mdj
```

This gets me a column called Results where each entry looks like:

```
{"Chronic": 0, "Probability": 0.0016}
```

Is there an efficient way to get Chronic in a column by itself?  Thanks!

Comment: could you pls add database tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

```
WITH jsons (x)  
AS  
(  
    -- replace this part with your query
    Select a.x from (select '{"Chronic": 0, "Probability": 0.0016}' x ) as a, (SELECT 1 as y union select 2 as y ) as b
)  
select 
    (SELECT value FROM OPENJSON(x,'$') where [key]='Chronic') as "Chronic", 
    (SELECT value FROM OPENJSON(x,'$') where [key]='Probability') as "Probability" 
from jsons;
```

[image]

I think you can change the @json equation to use your query. But I cannot try since I don't have your tables...

BTW, I assume you are using MSSQL...

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Would I set the @json like this:

SET @json=SELECT DISTINCT
    JSON_QUERY(mdj.value, '$.Results[0]') [Results]
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.parameter1 = t1.parameter1
    AND t2.parameter2 = 'ASDF'
JOIN table3 t3 ON oad.parameter3 = oa.parameter3 
    AND t3.parameter4 = 11
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t3.MetaDataJSON) as mdj
FOR JSON AUTO

because that doesn't seem to work... it says "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'."

Yes, I believe I am running MS-SQL

Comment: Use parenthesis before and after select. @json=(Select....)

Comment: Ah thanks, but this still doesn't quite work.  Here is what my @ json value looks like, if I do SELECT @ json after filling it with the query:

[{"Results":{"chronic": 0, "probability": 0.00433}},{"Results":{"chronic": 0, "probability": 0.00029}}]

but then when I do your last part, with the nested SELECT values, I get a small 1-row table with columns Chronic and Probability, both with NULL as their values.  Is it because the Results key still hasn't been removed from the json structure?

Comment: I updated the solution. Now it can convert multiple lines. Be sure that your query returns a single column with Json string

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this, maybe because I don't know exactly which part to replace with my query.  Is it the green dummy json structure in that example?  Could you perhaps edit the example and paste the following:   SELECT DISTINCT...FOR JSON AUTO    at the exact spot my query is supposed to go?  And yes, the query alone returns a single column with one row in this format: 

    [{"results":{"chronic": 0, "probability": 0.0018}},{"results":{"chronic": 0, "probability": 0.0023}}]

although the column name is something like JSON_F52E2B61-18A1... which is strange